# How to distinct records in Dynamics X++?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I need to remove repeated rows from my query, but I can't get the expected result. I researched I found out I should use `GROUP BY` but if I do use that I don't get the results I was getting before. Is this the correct way to distinct records in X++? By the way, I'm using 6 tables, here's my X++ Query:

```
SELECT RecId, City, BuildingCompliment
    FROM %1 GROUP BY RecId JOIN Location FROM %2
        OUTER JOIN StateId, Name FROM %3
        OUTER JOIN ISOcode FROM %4
        OUTER JOIN CurrencyCode, Symbol, Txt FROM %5
        OUTER JOIN ShortName FROM %6
    WHERE (%1.ValidTo == DateTimeUtil::maxValue() || %1.ValidTo > DateTimeUtil::utcNow())
        && %2.Location == %1.Location
        && %3.CountryRegionId == %2.CountryRegionId && %3.StateId == %2.State
        && %4.CountryRegionId == %1.CountryRegionId
        && %5.CurrencyCode == %4.CurrencyCode
        && %6.LanguageId == 'EN-US' && %6.CountryRegionId == %1.CountryRegionId
```

Here's the result with `GROUP BY RecId`:

`RecId - Location - StateName`

```
5637145326 - 0 - 
5637145327 - 0 - 
5637145328 - 0 - 
5637146076 - 0 - 
5637146077 - 0 - 
5637150576 - 0 - 
5637150577 - 0 - 
5637150578 - 0 -
```

Here's without `GROUP BY RecId`:

```
5637150578 - 5637145326 - New York
...
5637150578 - 5637145326 - New York
```

All repeated. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Tables/Views used:

```
DirPartyPostalAddressView //%1
LogisticsPostalAddress //%2
LogisticsAddressState //%3
LogisticsAddressCountryRegion //%4
Currency //%5
LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation //%6
```

Edited query:

```
string sqlAxCommand = @"SELECT RecId, City, BuildingCompliment, Location, CountryRegionId FROM %2
                                        GROUP BY RecId, City, BuildingCompliment, Location, CountryRegionId
                                    OUTER JOIN StateId, Name FROM %3
                                        WHERE %3.CountryRegionId == %2.CountryRegionId 
                                           && %3.StateId         == %2.State
                                    OUTER JOIN ISOcode FROM %4
                                        WHERE %4.CountryRegionId == %2.CountryRegionId
                                    OUTER JOIN CurrencyCode, Symbol, Txt FROM %5
                                        WHERE %5.CurrencyCode == %4.CurrencyCode
                                    OUTER JOIN ShortName FROM %6
                                        WHERE %6.CountryRegionId  == %2.CountryRegionId
                                           && %6.LanguageId       == 'EN-US'
                                    EXISTS JOIN %1
                                        WHERE %1.Location         == %2.Location
                                           && %1.IsPostalAddress  == NoYes::Yes";
```

Comment: It would help if you could replace %1-%6 with the actual table names.

Comment: @10p sure, I just updated my question.

Comment: Is it feasible to create a (static) method in X++ and call that from C#. In this way you could use all standard X++ functions and classes. If absolutely necessary you could also execute direct SQL from X++ (just don't forget to include the dataAreaId and/or the partition ;)

Comment: @VelislavMarinov I get that, but our goal is to use only C# calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect you had to use `GROUP BY RecId, City, BuildingCompliment`.

**Updated:**

If you need to join on `Location` and `CountryRegionId`, you need to add them to `GROUP BY` as well:

```
LogisticsPostalAddress          logisticsPostalAddress;
LogisticsAddressState           logisticsAddressState;
LogisticsAddressCountryRegion   logisticsAddressCountryRegion;
LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation logisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation;
Currency            currency;
DirPartyLocation    dirPartyLocation;
utcdatetime         _validFrom  = DateTimeUtil::utcNow();
utcdatetime         _validTo    = DateTimeUtil::maxValue();

SELECT validTimeState(_validFrom, _validTo) RecId, City, BuildingCompliment, Location, CountryRegionId FROM logisticsPostalAddress
    GROUP BY RecId, City, BuildingCompliment, Location, CountryRegionId
OUTER JOIN StateId, Name FROM logisticsAddressState
    WHERE logisticsAddressState.CountryRegionId == logisticsPostalAddress.CountryRegionId 
       && logisticsAddressState.StateId         == logisticsPostalAddress.State
OUTER JOIN ISOcode FROM logisticsAddressCountryRegion
    WHERE logisticsAddressCountryRegion.CountryRegionId == logisticsPostalAddress.CountryRegionId
OUTER JOIN CurrencyCode, Symbol, Txt FROM currency
    WHERE currency.CurrencyCode == logisticsAddressCountryRegion.CurrencyCode
OUTER JOIN ShortName FROM logisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation
    WHERE logisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation.CountryRegionId  == logisticsPostalAddress.CountryRegionId
       && logisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation.LanguageId       == 'EN-US'
EXISTS JOIN dirPartyLocation
    WHERE dirPartyLocation.Location         == logisticsPostalAddress.Location
       && dirPartyLocation.IsPostalAddress  == NoYes::Yes;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately no, I got the same result with only RecId and with all my projection fields.

Comment: I added an example to my answer - can you check if it works for you?

Comment: I don't know if you tried this, but it doesn't even compile. Could I have miss anything on you example?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: I added an example that does compile. I restructured your query a bit to exclude a View from it.

Comment: Thanks again. Why did you remove the view, was it not needed? Also I see you used validTimeState instead of comparing the dates, that already checks the ValidTo field?

Comment: I tried to streamline the query, and the view wasn't of much help here. Yes, `validTimeState` already checks the `ValidTo` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I still can't get results. I edited your query since I'm using .NetBusinessConnector. Please check my edited post. Also, if I use validTimeState I get a compile error, even changing its contents to DateTimeUtil...

Comment: I checked the query in my enviornment, it did return results. You cannot use `DateTimeUtil` inside the `validTimeState` brackets, you need to use variables. If you are not using `validTimeState` at all then records with future-dated `ValidFrom` will be excluded from the result.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I'm writing a C# code that connects to Dynamics and if I write the code the way you did (Dynamics style :D) it'll not compile. Do you have any suggestions for me? How could I achieve this?

Comment: That's quite a different issue and you can try creating a new question if you have difficulties in C#. Alternatively you can try modifying your original query, e.g. try using `GROUP BY RecId, City, BuildingCompliment, Location, CountryRegionId` in the original query (with a view), try removing outer joins for debugging purposes, etc.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have problems with C#. I can run several queries at the C# project and they work. I get a list of all Dynamics Countries for instance. The problem is with this specific requirement in which I need to list all addresses. I can't use variable declaration inside that query. I can only use x++ select statements.

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing a lot these pasts months in Dynamics Ax and most of the time when getting the duplicate records like you are describing it's incorrect joins. I would look under each individual table and make sure the joins are correct. Sometimes Ax will give you an auto join that may look right but isn't completely what you need. These situations happen quite often as you move away from Base Ax. I would recommend Switching the Inner joins and OuterJoins play with that get one record. When you deal with the LogisticselectronicAddress Table it doesn't like to share and create dups when used with inventtable and a few main others. You could also try making individual views and linking them together in C#. Hope this helps. Also ExistsJoin may not function completely how you want it to. Try taking that join out first and reworking it a bit. Go ahead and delete if you don't think it's adequate.

Comment: Hey Ben, welcome to Stack Overflow. While this answer might solve the problem, it's not particularly concise, and leans more toward speculation than a solid answer. I'd suggest editing it and improving it when you have a chance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've played a while with my query even before posting to no avail. Anyway, I decided to use AIF Services since it's gonna solve my issue and will give me a lil bit more flexibility.